# QGIS 3.10 Add ring to shapefile - "Unknown error"

Tags: qgis, shapefile, error, ring

I have a polygon shapefile layer with some overlapping polygons, styled using categorised labelling with different styles layered on top of the others.
I would normally use the "Add ring" tool to draw around the top polygon and cut the shape out of the bottom polygon.

This has worked all but tow of the styled features, i.e. I can draw a ring around the trees, cutting a circle out of the hard standing within that layer but if I try doing the same thing and drawing a ring into the grassland (same layer), it doesn't work "unknown error has occurred".

Hard standing and grassland are both set to level 0 while trees are level 2. So I am unsure why it works for one but no the other.

What is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide data?

Comment: Sorry no - I'm accessing it via a remote desktop which wont let me download to the machine unfortunately. But the whole layer was made at the same time in the same way...

Comment: It's not like you couldn't access stack via the remote, but anyway. Have you checked for faulty geometries?

Comment: Yeah - all fine, thank you for the idea though